# Word2010 rescaling image when opening position dialog

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

My document contains a single quadratic 33x33 px image (tif).

When I open the 'position' dialog:

- if the image is embedded, it gets scaled to 103%.
- if it is linked, it gets scaled down to 97%.

This happens in Word2010, Word2013 and Word2016.
In Word2007, it stays at 100%.
A sample 3x3 image, does not get scaled in newer Word versions.

The software I work with requires Images not to be scaled inside Word, no matter their size.

Can this automatic scaling be disabled somehow?

Comment: Word looks DPI of the image and if it's something else than 96dpi, it'll be scaled to 96dpi. Can you change your image to be 96dpi?

Comment: The image is on 600dpi for print.  
We are expected to deliver the images separated from the docx file.  
I guess I will scale down the image, link it, then Word should not scale it.  
In the final print document, I still deliver the 600dpi image.

Comment: Simply scaling down the image to 96dpi, but keeping the same amount of pixels in it, makes that picture very large in Word.

I don't think there is an easy solution, so I will have  to talk to the developers of the checking-tool for scaling.

Comment: There is an option "Do not compress images" which disables this behaviour.
No need to downscale anything.

Thank you for your comment, it hinted me to this!

Comment: You're welcome! I'll add an answer with your discovery with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word looks DPI of the image and if it's something else than 96dpi, it'll be scaled to 96dpi. This can cause problems with images not looking the same when added to MS Word.

@sbulka: There is an option "Do not compress images" which disables this behaviour.
No need to downscale anything.